# R Flatten list to list by columns

Tags: r, list

I have a list witch look like that :

```
created_time : chr "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name : chr "John"
message : chr "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
created_time : chr "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name : chr "Peter"
message : chr "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
created_time : chr "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name : chr "Mike"
message : chr "Nam at euismod risus"
```

And I would like to transform it like this...

```
created_time : char [1:3]  "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000" "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000" "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name: char [1:3] "John" "Peter" "Mike"
message: char [1:3] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua" "Nam at euismod risus"
```

It should be a easy way to do this but I can't find. Any help?

Comment: Please provide your data in reproducible form.  If x is your input show the output of dput(x) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
l1 <- split(unlist(l, use.names=FALSE), names(l))
str(l1)
#List of 3
#$ created_time: chr [1:3] "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000" "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000" "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
#$ from.name   : chr [1:3] "John" "Peter" "Mike"
#$ message     : chr [1:3] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua" "Nam at euismod risus"
```

Or another variant is

```
with(stack(l), split(values, ind))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives assuming in the first two that the input is as in `Lines` and in the third that the input is as in `L`

**1)** This gives a data frame whose first column is the first field and the remaining columns are the second fiels for that first field.

```
Lines <- 'created_time : chr "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name : chr "John"
message : chr "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
created_time : chr "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name : chr "Peter"
message : chr "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
created_time : chr "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
from.name : chr "Mike"
message : chr "Nam at euismod risus"'

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ":", as.is = TRUE)
aggregate(V2 ~ V1, DF, c)
```

**2)** Another possibility is the following which produces a data frame with one column for each of create_time, from.name and message with the second fields pasted together with commas separating them.

```
read.dcf(textConnection(Lines), all = TRUE)
```

**3)** If the input looks like this rather than as assumed in the prior two points then use `split`:

```
L <- list(created_time = "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000", 
          from.name = "John",
          message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          created_time = "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000",
          from.name = "Peter",
          message = "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
          created_time = "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000",
          from.name = "Mike",
          message = "Nam at euismod risus")

sapply(split(L, names(L)), c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for:

```
l <- list(created_time="2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000",from.name="John",message="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",created_time="2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000",from.name="Peter",message="Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",created_time="2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000",from.name="Mike",message="Nam at euismod risus");
str(l);
## List of 9
##  $ created_time: chr "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
##  $ from.name   : chr "John"
##  $ message     : chr "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
##  $ created_time: chr "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
##  $ from.name   : chr "Peter"
##  $ message     : chr "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
##  $ created_time: chr "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
##  $ from.name   : chr "Mike"
##  $ message     : chr "Nam at euismod risus"
ns <- unique(names(l));
res <- setNames(lapply(ns,function(n) unname(do.call(c,l[names(l)==n]))),ns);
str(res);
## List of 3
##  $ created_time: chr [1:3] "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000" "2015-12-30T04:04:09+0000" "2016-12-30T04:04:09+0000"
##  $ from.name   : chr [1:3] "John" "Peter" "Mike"
##  $ message     : chr [1:3] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" "Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua" "Nam at euismod risus"
```